# jQuery UI Dialog using iframe URL

Tags: javascript, iframe, dialog, modal-dialog

I've used nyroModal and Fancybox as tools for websites but in this instance I must use jQuery UI's dialog tool. I need this dialog to load a page. I believe I've done this before but everything I come across seems more complex than it should be. Can't I use something like...

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      url: http://www.google.com
      });

<button id="dialog">Open Dialog</button>
```

and have the page open in a simple iframe? Thanks in advance.

---

I did find that I have this code,

```
<script>
  //$.fx.speeds._default = 500;  
  $(function() {    
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({      
    autoOpen: false,      
    show: "fade",   
    hide: "fade",
            modal: true,            
            open: function () {$(this).load('nom-1-dialog-add-vessels.html');},                     
            height: 'auto',            
            width: 'auto',        
            resizable: true,    
            title: 'Vessels'    });     

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {      
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );      
    return false;   
    });  
  });  
  </script>

<div id="dialog"></div><button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

but it's not loading the actual page.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`url` is not one of the options in [jQuery UI dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).

One of the things that has worked for me is to have an `iframe` inside the `div` that is your dialog, and set its url property on the `open` event.

Like:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <iframe id="myIframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>
<button id="dialogBtn">Open Dialog</button>
```

And JS:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 600,
    open: function(ev, ui){
             $('#myIframe').attr('src','http://www.jQuery.com');
          }
});

$('#dialogBtn').click(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

You would find that you need some styling on the iframe to get it look nice, though.

```
#myIframe{
  height: 580px;
}
```

EDIT: Working version - http://jsbin.com/uruyob/1/edit

Comment: That seems to make sense, but there is an empty box on my page.

Comment: the js bin eg looks so simple and easy, but I already get an empty box on my page and text "your iframe below" is just lying next to it and nothing happens when I click the button! I also tried including all the jquery-ui-js files. Nothing!

Comment: You might want to add type='button' to the button. Otherwise, if your button is in a form, it will submit it.

Comment: Hoe can I do the same thing on Blazor server app?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Floyd Pink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218882/floyd-pink) and your code, I have consolidated an code. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/Nz9Q8/

```
 $(function () {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    modal: true,
    open: function (ev, ui) {
      $('#myIframe').src = 'http://www.w3schools.com';
    },
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    resizable: true,
    title: 'Vessels'
  });

  $("#opener").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: You could remove the src from the `iframe` and change this line `$('#myIframe').src = 'http://www.w3schools.com';` to `$('#myIframe').attr('src','http://www.w3schools.com');`

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar thing. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/P2Q5U/

```
<div id="dialogContent" title="Basic dialog">
  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
</div>
<button id="dialog">Open Dialog</button>

 $(function () {
   $("#dialogContent").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true
   });

   $('#dialog').click(function () {
     $("#dialogContent").dialog( "open" );
   });
 });
```

Comment: can that dynamically size?

Comment: You need to specify the size for both the dialog and the iframe.